# Field of point source - Coulomb's law & propagation by induction

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

We know that a point positive charge at (0,0) would create an electric field all around itself, and in particular along the $x$-axis.

Along the positive $x$-axis the electric field will point to the right (if the $x$-axis is oriented from left to right).

Finally we know that fields really propagate by an EM wave and don't instantaneously appear as Coulomb's law might imply.

But here's the thing: an Electric field pointing in the positive $x$-axis will not propagate along the $x$-axis. Depending on the magnetic field (induced by the electric field), it would appear to go either along the $y$-axis or along the $z$-axis.

Yet somehow it should propagate along the $x$-axis (an electric field pointing in the $x$-axis also propagates along the $x$-axis).

How does that work out?

Thanks for any help. While anything helps, an ideal answer might include the directions of the fields in a few iterations of the induction along the $x$-axis.

PS

Usually the fields are treated statically by Coulomb's law, but initially they propagate out of the particle at the speed of light. Sometimes this has practical consequences - for example if the field starts in water and continues on to air the direction of propagation might bend from one medium to the next. Hence the propagation mechanism, even of a static field, is of some practical value too, besides simply being of theoretical interest to understand.

For the positive charge in the question, we can assume that the particle just appeared and we are looking at the short initial duration as the field info spreads out nearby the particle.

It'd be easy to just say apply Coulomb's law & forget about the whole thing. And usually that's where books leave you. But I'm trying to integrate various concepts together.

Comment: *Depending on the magnetic field (induced by the electric field)* Do stationary charges generate a magnetic field?

Comment: Let's say the charge just appeared. There is E flux. The E flux would generate B fields all around it. As you say, when the system has had time to evolve, there is no B field. My guess was that the B fields curl very closely around the E flux lines (a static E flux always exists), and therefore cancel each other. I'm not sure if that's the correct view, or how the field wave spreads away from the charge.

Comment: "isn't it the case that whenever there is E flux (even static), a B field forms around it":  No, this is not the case.  It is perfectly valid to have a static electric flux without a B-field present.  "Usually the fields are treated statically by Columb's law. But initially they propagate out at the speed of light."  What do you mean by "initially"?  You seem to be positing a situation where a charge pops into existence and the field lines start to radiate outward.  But you can't create a charge out of nothing — charge is conserved.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Michael, could you please explain how the lack of B field congrues with the law saying that there is a B field whenever there is either current or E flux? As to the second point, it's not crucial to me. As long as the charge is there the field would continue propagating outwards. So I can take back it having appeared without altering the question. Perhaps it had moved and finally stopped at (0,0). From here I'd like to find out how the field info is spreading. Thanks!

Comment: There has to be a magnetic field whenever there is a *changing* $\vec{E}$-flux.  But if the electric flux is not changing (i.e., there is a constant amount of flux at all times) then you can very easily have $\vec{B} = 0$.  For example, if you've had a point charge sitting at the origin for a very long time, then the electric flux through any surface is constant, and there is no magnetic field.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Perhaps I'm misinterpreting the law. But then they would show a capacitor with a constant flux across it, and say that as a result of the flux (displacement current) a B field is supported. Isn't it the case that in Maxwell's equation the displacement current term is in terms of flux, rather than change in flux?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you've misinterpreted the law.  In Maxwell's equation you have $\nabla \times \vec{B} = \mu_0 \vec{J} + \mu_0 \epsilon_0 \frac{\partial \vec{E}}{\partial t}.$  If $\vec{E}$ is constant (and there's no current) then $\nabla \times \vec{B} = 0$, which is consistent with $\vec{B} = 0$.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert thanks for your help, I now see that no doubt I've misinterpreted Maxwell's eq. The story with the constant flux through a capcitor supporting a B field led me astray. Come to think of it, the flux remains across the capacitor even when it's charged and no more current goes around the circuit. No current goes around the circuit, no B field, yet there is static flux across the capacitor (which again shows that a static flux is not producing a B field). With that understanding, is the spreading out of the E field away from the charged particle NOT a matter of an EM wave?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146844/discussion-between-michael-seifert-and-daniel).

Answer (score 1):

With a positive point charge at rest at the origin, there is no induction. The system is static.

Like you say, the electric field along the $x$-axis points along the $x$-axis. This means that a positive test charge placed on the axis will experience a force moving it along the axis. In this situation the dynamic evolution is not considered, nor is the back reaction on the system.

You are possibly confusing the orthogonality of the electric and magnetic fields in a traveling EM wave (electrodynamics) with the stationary (electrostatic) setup described above.

To address the actual interaction of the charge and the E field that produces this force requires field theory. For example, tree level QED describes the Coulomb force. The polarizations of the exchanged virtual photon will reflect the orthogonality of the E and B fields that are familiar from classical electromagnetism.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; yet, isn't it the case that the static field propagates out of the charge as a wave at the speed of light? And wouldn't that propagation be an EM propagation by induction? Like you said, for a static charge usually there is no point to consider how the field information propagates, you can simply apply Columb's law on a test charge. But for example, if the particle is in water, the direction of the field would bend at the air boundry. Or if there is a ground plane, the E field won't be seen on the other side of the ground plane as it can't go through a conductor.

Comment: Although in the ground plane case, the E field might simply be canceled by superposition. If that's the case, the static analysis still applies. All the same, I keep thinking how does the spreading out of the field wave out & away from the charge, at the speed of light, can be explained from an EM point of view? The fact that the field propagates away at the speed of light seems like a clue that it spreads as an EM wave.

Comment: Thanks again for answering the question. I've added a +1 upvote. I've figured out a bit more on this, so probably some of what I've in the comments above is incorrect. I ultimately also ended writing my own version of an answer to share my updated perspective.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks kindly to Michael Seifert who altruistically spend a considerable amount of time discussing this question with me.

I believe I've got the answer now, so let me summarize below:

1. When the positive charge just appears (charge is conserved, so it really doesn't appear as much as arrive at a point), a change in E flux induces B fields, which change the B flux, inducing an E flux again, and so on which makes EM waves propagate radially outward from the charge (the details of this mechanism are a topic in of itself).
2. These EM waves are short lived because the E flux of the point positive charge is static, and the change in flux is only effective for a short while when the particle has just appeared.
3. The EM waves propagating outward do not directly induce the static E field along the path of their propagation. Indeed after the EM waves passes over a point, the non-static E & B fields return to 0.
4. Yet besides the induction where the E and B fields are perpendicular, that is EM wave induction, there is second mode of induction away from the charge. The induction along the X-axis for a point charge at (0, 0) is an example of the second kind. It propagates radially outward, leaving behind E fields over points it passes. These would be the static fields. This propagation is also by induction and should be visible in a FDTD simulation. In this case the E and B fields are not perpendicular and the induction doesn't carry forward energy (the B fields are short lived at the front of the induction, while the E fields remain).
5. In my question, maybe I've already edited it out, I've incorrectly said that an E flux produces a B field. As Michael kindly pointed out only a change in the E flux produces a B field. I think I was confused by the case of a flux between the plates of a capacitor. When this flux is changing there is B field around the capacitor, just as if it were "real" current. But when the capacitor had charged, and no additional current flow is occurring, the static E flux does not result in B fields around it.

To go back to the scenario described in my question: there induction from the charge along the X-axis, but it energy flow doesn't accompany it. It leaves behind static E fields along the X-axis. In other directions there is a brief EM wave propagation, carrying forward power and having its E and B fields perpendicular (a "brief" wave because nothing continues to generate it after the charge appears, but it would travel forward potentially forever until absorbed).

The static and EM induction follow the same rules. Only given the initial direction of the fields, the behavior varies.